# Does computation within predicate run on every iteration?

Tags: swift, swift2, predicate

When there's a computation within a predicate, does it execute on every iteration or does just execute the first time?

For example:
`items.filter { $0.propA > (343424 * 752 / 0.43) }`

Does this calculation run on every iteration (`343424 * 752 / 0.43`) or only the first time. I'm wondering if I have to inconvenience myself every time something like:

```
let calc = 343424 * 752 / 0.43
items.filter { $0.propA > calc }
```

It can also have implications if I have `NSDate()` within a predicate where it will be a moving target.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the optimizer.  Any compiler worth it's salt will evaluate the constant expression at run time and emit only code for `$0.propA > someResult`  Now, note that this is a special case where the code is clearly a constant value.  The ability of the compiler and optimizer to identify constant expressions may vary depending on compiler settings and phase of the moon. Also note, that expressions with possible side effects, such as `NSDate()` should (must) be executed each iteration of the closure to be functionally correct (`NSDate()` may have side effects and hence can't be optimized out, not to mention the fact that the NSDate() is different in pointer and value on each iteration)